# What is the difference between "llover" and "lluvia"?

Tags: verbos, significado, sustantivos

Both *llover* and *lluvia* represent rain.

What's the difference between these words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Llover" is the verb "to rain". For example,

> Llueve mucho

Means "it rains a lot".

On the other hand, "la lluvia" is a noun which means "the rain". For example,

> No me gusta la lluvia

Means "I do not like the rain".

Comment: There is also "Está lloviendo" = "It **is** raining"